# MySQL + Django: No obj.id after save()

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, auto-increment

Using Django and MySQL. I save the model and no id appears. Seen some similar issues with PostgreSQL and with bigintegerfields, but neither of those seem to apply here. Any ideas? The client does receive a primary key in the id field in the database via MySQL auto-increment.

Thanks!

```
class Client(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    first_name = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    last_name = models.TextField(blank=True)


>>> client = models.Client(last_name="Last", first_name="First")
>>> client.last_name
'Last'
>>> client.save()
>>> client.id
>>> client.last_name
'Last'
>>> client.id
>>> client.pk
>>>
```

And in the database:

```
id      first_name  last_name
------------------------------------------
14      First       Last
```

Comment: [You don't really need to explicitly add the primary key to the model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields).

Comment: True. It was an artifact from a tool I used to generate the models from a pre-existing schema.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Rebus says in the comments, you don't need to define the primary key explicitly. But if you do, you must make sure it is an autoincrement field - ie `AutoField` - not a basic `IntegerField` as you have. The way you have it, there's no way to get a new ID, which is why it's blank on save.

Comment: For anyone else with this problem, I had to delete and recreate all my models in order to get this change to work, but it works now. Thanks Daniel!

Answer (score 0):

System generated database keys must be set by the database or else you won't have a multi-user database.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you are saying and how it could potentially solve my issue. I'm sorry, I am pretty new to this stuff.

Comment: A multi-user database handles the generation and insertion of a system generated key and should be designed to reject any attempts to circumvent doing so.  What you are encountering is an indication of how MySQL rejects the attempt.